# Command line arguments for launching Ubuntu on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, sublime-text-3

I've got Terminus installed on SublimeText (on Windows 10) and have used James231's code from GitHub to set up a keybind to launch a Ubuntu terminal. Is there a command line argument I can use to get it to launch in a specific directory?

[Screenshot of my current setup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Ouv.jpg)

Edit-Adding code from screenshot to make post searchable, easy to copy and paste:

```
    // Open ubuntu when Alt+2 is pressed
    {
        "keys": ["alt+2"],
        "command": "terminus_open",
         "args" : {
            // Tell terminus to use Git Bash
            // Replace the path below with your path to Git Bash
            "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\\ubuntu.exe"],

            "cwd": "${file_path:${folder}}",
            "panel_name": "Terminus"
         }
    },
```

You see I've got the directory correct and the terminal launches Ubuntu correctly using the 'alt+2' keybind, but I don't know how to get it to open in the directory of the file that I'm working with. I see that "${file_path:${folder}}" references the path of the currently open file but I don't know how to insert it into the launch command. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Terminus, so I can't help you with the exact settings, but ...

The `ubuntu.exe` command is a bit (but not quite) deprecated for launching and managing WSL.  It does seem to *always* launch into `~` from what I can see (although it's been years since I've used that command directly for that purpose).

Try the much more capable `wsl.exe` command.  It should use whatever directory that Terminus passes its process, so for starters try:

```
"cmd": ["wsl"],
```

or, if you need the full path:

```
"cmd": ["C:\\Windows\\system32\\wsl.exe"],
```

If that fails, try passing a directory directly using `wsl --cd`

```
"cmd": ["wsl --cd ${file_path:${folder}}]",
```

^^^ You may need to escape-quote the directory if it includes spaces

Note that if you *do* want to launch directly to your home directory with `wsl` (since it uses the *current* directory by default), use `wsl ~`.

Comment: Awesome info. I was able to find wsl.exe in its directory and did this:

    "cmd": ["C:\\Windows\\system32\\wsl.exe"],

And then left cwd as is:

    "cwd": "${file_path:${folder}}",

And that works exactly as I wanted it to. Thanks very much.

Comment: Glad to help.  I went ahead and updated the answer with the full-path option.  Figured it would work without that, since `C:\Windows\system32\` is in the Windows path by default, but perhaps Terminus or Sublime need the full path.  Thanks for the update and info!